# Upgrade JDBC Driver module in Jboss EAP 6

Tags: oracle, module, jboss, upgrade

Our application is deployed as an EAR and runs on Jboss EAP 6.
Few years back Oracle jdbc driver was added as a core module in Jboss, path com/oracle.
In standalone.xml the datasource is configured with the driver that points to the module name as mentioned below -

```
<datasource   ....>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="testOracleDriver" module="com.oracle">
        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</datasource
```

Oracle driver is also added as a maven dependency in pom file and the oracle driver jar is added as a module in application.xml.
This application.xml is placed in EAR's META-INF folder.

Now there is a requirement to upgrade oracle driver version to 19. To achieve this can we just upgrade the desired oracle driver dependency in pom.xml with version 19. Will the application then use the oracle 19 driver as it will be specified as a module in application.xml that is placed EAR's META-INF?
Since the datasource refers to oracle module, should we also update module.xml (under com/oracle/main) with the correct JAR version and drop the correct JAR in this module?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar requirement in our project to update to oracle 12c.
We Updated dependency in *pom.xml* and also updated *datasource* in standalone.xml, something  like this-

```
<drivers>
        <driver name="testOracleDriver" module="com.oracle" slot="oracle19">
        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
```

The *slot* given here is the folder you can create inside Jboss modules on path com/oracle/oracle19. And then add new jdbc driver and module.xml inside.

We did not add any entry in application.xml as Jboss will load datasource by default because of the entry in standalone.xml

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. One quick question, what is the scope of oracle jdbc driver dependency in your application's pom.xml? Also instead of adding a new module isn't it a possible solution to modify existing module.xml with the new jar and replace the new Jar in the folder, that way we don't have to make any modification to standalone.xml.

Comment: The scope would be _provided_. And yes, you can also just modify existing module.xml and replace old jar. That would work too.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. The application I am working on is an old application and it has oracle driver dependency added with the "compile" scope in the EAR. Also the jar exists in Jboss module and the module is referenced in standalone.xml as mentioned in my question. The driver jar dependency scope should be changed to "provided" and Jboss oracle module should be updated with the latest JAR, this will ensure the  application also uses dependency specified in Jboss module, does this sound right to you?

Comment: Yes that is right. In my application the dependency was already set to _provided_ before update so we did not really bothered about it.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help!